# IBM MQ DLQ message cause MQRC 3023

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a java program using javax.jms* classes to publish message to a MQ topic (MQv7.5), few messages goes to DLQ with following details in in DLQ Header,

Format  'No Format'
Reason  '3023'
   -> 3023  0x00000bcf  MQRCCF_MD_FORMAT_ERROR

**Header Info in Message:**

```
DeadLetter Header Information
Encoding    'Default Encoding'
Character Set   'ibm1208'
Format  'No Format'
Reason  '3023'
Destination Queue Manager   'QMGRSTCRT1'
Destination Queue   ' '
Put Appl Name   'WebSphere MQ Client for Java'
Put Appl Type   'Java'
Date/Time   '20150127-19271043'

RFH Header Information  

Encoding    'Default Encoding'
Character Set   'ibm1208'
Flags   '0'
Format  'No Format'
Name Value Pair 'UNIQUE_CONNECTION_ID', '414D512045414D51534331202020202054B921242739A302 MQPSCommand Publish MQPSTopic CUSTOMER_EVENT MQPSPubOpts NoReg ' 

MQMD

Put Date    'Tue Jan 07 13:38:44 CST 2015'
Message ID:     '414D512045414D51534331202020202054B9212427896148'
Correlation ID:     '414D512045414D515343312020202020542907882CEF7E04'
Group ID:   '000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
Account Token:      '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
AppID Data:     ' '
App Origin Data:    ' '
Backout Count:      '0'
Character Set:      'ibm1208'
Expiry:     '14'
Format:     'RFH version 1'
Encoding:   'Default Encoding'
Feedback:   'None'
Message Flags:      'None'
Offset:     '0'
Sequence Number:    '1'
Type:   'Datagram'
Persistence:    'Not Persistent'
Priority:   '4'
Put Appl Name:      'QMGRSTCRT1 '
Put Appl Type:      '26'
Reply To Queue Manager:     'QMGRSTCRT1 '
Reply To Queue Name:    ' '
Report:     'Default Report Options, New Msg ID, Copy Msg ID to Correlation ID, Dead Letter Q'
User ID:    'tempid '
Version:    '2'
Content Type:   'writestring'

JMS properties
JMSDeliveryMode 2
JMSDestination  topic://CUSTOMER_EVENT
JMSTimestamp    1422387524491
mcd.Msd jms_object
JMSExpiration   1422391124491
```

Adding Qmgr logs corresponding to the DLQ message..

```
AMQ5882: WebSphere MQ Publish/Subscribe broker has written a message to the
dead-letter queue.

EXPLANATION:
The broker has written a message to the dead-letter queue
(SYSTEM.DEADLETTER.QUEUE                        ) for reason
'3023:MQRCCF_MD_FORMAT_ERROR'. Note. To save log space, after the first
occurrence of this message for stream (TEST.PUBSUB
       ), it will only be written periodically.
ACTION:
If the message was not deliberately written to the dead-letter queue, for
example by a message broker exit, determine why the message was written to the
dead-letter queue, and resolve the problem that is preventing the message from
being sent to its destination.
```

Code Snippet used in Program..

```
    private TopicConnection topicConnection = null;
private TopicSession topicSession = null;
private TopicPublisher topicPub = null ;
private TopicSubscriber topicSub = null ;
```

protected void createTopicPub(String clientID,long msgLifeTime) throws JMSException {
        closeTopicPub();

```
    if (topicSession == null)
        createTopicConnectionWithClientID(clientID);

    Topic the_topic = (Topic)topicSession.createTopic(topicName);
    topicPub = topicSession.createPub(the_topic);           
    topicPub.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
    topicPub.setPriority(4);
    //SET the time to expire the message
    topicPub.setTimeToLive(msgLife);        
    topicConnection.start();        
}
public void sendMessage(String msg) throws JMSException {
    TextMessage message = null ;
    if (topicPub == null) {
        throw new JMSException("TopicPub is null");
    }
    message = topicSession.createTextMessage(msg);
    topicPub.publish(message);              
    log.debug("Message sent");
```

}

```
private void createTopicConnWithClientID(String clientID) throws JMSException {
            closeTopicConnection(); 
        MQTopicConnectionFactory topicCF = new MQTopicConnectionFactory();
        topicCF.setHostName(hostName);
        topicCF.setPort(portNumber);
        topicCF.setQueueManager(queueManager);
        topicCF.setChannel(channel);
        topicCF.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);        
        // create connection and session
        topicConnection = topicCF.createTopicConnection();      
        topicConnection.setClientID(clientID);              
        topicSession = topicConnection.createTopicSession(transactional,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
}
```

what is causing the MD format error? where is the correction required?

Comment: Are you using Queued Pub/Sub in MQ v7.5? What is the version of MQ Client?

Comment: MQ java classes jars v7.5 are used ..

Answer (score 4):

This error code, [`MQRCCF_MD_FORMAT_ERROR`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q046270_.htm), means that the MQMD Format field of the message had a value that was not `MQFMT_ADMIN`.

There are various parts of IBM MQ that expect to be given a message with Format = `MQFMT_ADMIN`:-

- Command Server
- Queued Pub/Sub

From the provided AMQERR01.LOG error message we can see that the feature in question is the Queued Pub/Sub broker.

Since you're on V7.5 you don't need to be using queued pub/sub, you could directly use the topics. You say your application is Java, but don't mention whether it is JMS or not. The use queued pub/sub vs direct use of topics is something made under the covers in JMS, so you might not be aware you are doing it. Check that `PROVIDERVERSION` is set to 7 and not 6.

Comment: Hi Morag, we are using JMS and we didn't use the PROVIDERVERSION property.

Comment: Ok. We probably need some more clues then. Would it be possible for you to update the question with the full message contents?

Comment: Is this the message that ended up on the DLQ? Where is the DLQ header? A browse with amqsbcg sample will be fine.

Comment: Well, that is interesting, the DLQ Header shows that this DLQ message was not written because the command server or pub/sub engine was unhappy with the contents of the message, and there is no queue in the DLQ header. It was written by the Java Client. I wonder if @calanais can help further.

Comment: I have added qmgr logs as well.. corresponding to this DLQ msg

Comment: OK, so we now can see that you are using the old Queued Pub/Sub mechanism instead of the new (as of MQ V7) Put to Topic. That was why you were asked to check Provider Version. So now we need to work out why you are not invoking the correct Pub/Sub mechanism. Can you provide a snippet of your code that is using TEST.PUBSUB (after double checking you have PROVIDERVERSION set to 7)

Comment: Yes Morag, i didn't set "setProviderVersion". I copied the snippet of code. What points the difference in  Queued Pub Sub and Direct put to Topic ? Please share a documentation link regarding this, so i can read it.